# SQL explicit join filter condition

Tags: sql, join, syntax, implicit

Using this relational schema, patient ID and staff ID are foreign keys with `id.staff` and `pid.patient` being unique keys:

```
staff(ID, fname, lname, role)
patient(pID, pFname, pLname, bdate, address, phone)
appointment(aptID, patientID, staffID, aptDate, aptTime)
procedures(procNum, pName, price)
aptDetail(aptID, procNo)
```

So say if I wanted to list the names of patients with appointments with a specific staff member, i.e John Smith, how would I do that explicitly?

I've managed implicitly, but I know this is kind of frowned upon, but I can't reach it without using `WHERE` statements.

Any help would be appreciated, any time I try and use `INNER JOIN` I seem to hit a wall if it's not a simple join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the type of query you're looking for?

```
select distinct pFname, pLname
from patient p
  join appointment a on p.pID = a.patientID
  join staff s on a.staffID = s.ID
where s.fname = 'John' and s.lname = 'Smith'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join

```
   select 
      a.pID
      , a.pFname
      , a.pLname
      , a.bdate
      , a.address
      , a.phone
      , b.aptDate
      , b.aptTime
      , c.fname
      , c.lname
      , c.role
   from patient a 
   INNER JOIN appointment b on b.patientID = a.pID
   INNER JOIN staff c on b.staffID = c.ID on concat(fname, ' ', lname ) ='John Smith'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work fine:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM appointment AS a
   INNER JOIN staff AS s ON a.staffID = s.pID
   INNER JOIN patient AS p ON a.patientID = p.pID
WHERE s.ID = <yourstaffid>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select staff.fname, staff.role,
patient.pfname, plname, appoitment.aotdate
from staff, patient, appointment
where patient.pid=appointment.patientId
and staff.id=appointment.staffid
```